# Bluemix Presence Insights Generic connector not working

Tags: ibm-cloud, connector, presenceinsights

I have a generic connector created in my Personal Insights console. This connector is assigned to a zone-floor,site-name.

I'm sending messages with the pi-swagger page. I'm using the `POST /conn-generic/v1/tenants/{tenantCode}/orgs/{orgCode` connector.

The message is the next

```
  "data": [
    {
      "deviceId": "11:11:22:33:44:66",
      "timestamp": 1461146935,
      "sensorCode": "2v7hq0bnz",
      "sensorRssi": -50
    }
  ]
```

with Response Code 202. I'm using the Sensor Strategy, but i can't see this visit in my zone.

This message is in Presence Insights because under the section Operations - Analysis I can see the success. I don't have any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this might be do to the RSSI being provided and the RSSI threshold set in the PI sensor document.  The `sensorRssi` must be larger than the threshold defined in the PI sensor document's properties, or else the event will be discarded.

You mentioned to support that you have adjusted the threshold to -30, and are now sending events in with a `sensorRssi` of -10.  There is a 5 minute cache period in the PI pipeline, and it's possible that you would not have received a visit if you sent an event immediately after updating the sensor document's threshold.  By now the cache would have been invalidated and the updated sensor doc retrieved.  Could you send in another event and verify whether or not you see a visit?